# Passing mutliple arguments between PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

Hi I have a php script that refers to another html file inside of its one of the button handlers. It passes an argument called serial_no_html, and inside the other html (change.html) I parse the url (window.location.href), and use it.

Code in PHP:

````
<form action="change.html" method="get"> <input type="submit" 
name="serial_no_html" id="serial_no_html" value="'.$serial_no.'"/></form>```
````

Code in change.html:

```
var element = document.getElementById("serialNumber");
var sn = getParameterByName('serial_no_html');
window.location.search;
element.innerHTML = sn;
```

This all works, how ever I need to send multiple parameters now. How exactly can that be done? With added & ? For example :

```
<form action="change.html" method="get"> <input type="submit" name="serial_no_html" 
    id="serial_no_html" value="'.$serial_no.' & name="second_parameter" 
    id="second_parameter_html" value="'.$second_parameter.'"/></form>
```

Did I get the syntax right?

Thanks
Ratin

Comment: Collect all parametters in an array then eco into input value at once, or use hidden inputs and collect them as an array like : `name="parameters[]"` on your way it can be done like this `value="'.$first_parameter.'","'.$second_parameter.'"` Or `value="'.$first_parameter.$second_parameter.'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put multiple names and values in the same `<input>`, you need to use multiple input fields. This is what `type="hidden"` inputs are for.

```
<form action="change.html" method="get"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="second_parameter" value="'.$second_parameter.'">
    <input type="submit" name="serial_no_html" id="serial_no_html" value="'.$serial_no.'"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. A follow up question, in change,html I have the following code to receive a bitmasked interger parameter and update the checkbox property based on which bits are on.
 
<script type="text/javascript"> var personality = getParameterByName('personality_html');if (($personality & 0x4) === 0x4) { document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked = true; } </script>

Comment: Don't put long code questions in comments. Post a new question.

Comment: Hi, never mind, I found the issue, its the extra $ in variable name which is invalid for javascript

Comment: `$` is perfectly fine in JavaScript.